# How do I implement malloc_trim(0) in ndk toolchains?

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, heap-memory

Because there is no function malloc_trim in ndk , so I want to find a way to implement malloc_trim(0) in ndk !

Answer (score 1):

A simple definition like the following should suffice:

```
int malloc_trim(size_t pad) { return 1; }
```

Better still is to see if whatever library you're compiling has a flag to disable the use of `malloc_trim` at all.

EDIT: According to [this post](https://blog.nsogroup.com/a-tale-of-two-mallocs-on-android-libc-allocators-part-2-jemalloc/), [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) is the default memory allocator. jemalloc uses `mmap` by default, not `sbrk`. Jemalloc automatically returns memory to the OS when certain conditions are met, so I would not bother trying to come up with a useful implementation for malloc_trim.

Comment: `return 0` would even be a correct implementation. "The malloc_trim() function returns 1 if memory was actually released back to the system, or 0 if it was not possible to release any memory."

Comment: But there is no function called malloc_trim in android-ndk . Do you konw how to release memory in heap when you build project with android-ndk ?

Comment: See edit: the default memory allocator doesn't use sbrk() and already gives memory back to the OS when needed